# How do I Process a Query in T-SQL that has a "Union All" but get the Second "Select" to always appear at the bottom?

Tags: sql, t-sql, union-all

How do I Process a Query in T-SQL that has a "Union All" but get the Second "Select" to always appear at the bottom? I have the following SQL...

```
select Policy.[Effective Date], Policy.[Policy #], CLIENT.[NAME], Policy.[Premium]
From Policy, Client 
Where Policy.[Effective Date] > '2000-11-11' AND Policy.[Policy Type] <> 'Quote' AND Client.[CLIENTID] = Policy.[CLIENTID] 

union all

select null, null, 'Totals', sum(Policy.[Premium])
From Policy, Client 
Where Policy.[Effective Date] > '2000-11-11' AND Policy.[Policy Type] <> 'Quote' AND Client. 
CLIENTID = Policy.CLIENTID
Order By CLIENT.NAME
```

But the result looks like...

[image]

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick: Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to add an extra fixed ordering column.** This is usually very efficient, because it usually uses `Merge Concatenation`, [as explained by Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/09/t-sql-queries/avoiding-sorts-merge-join-concatenation).

**I would advise you not to use the ancient and deprecated `,` joining syntax. I also advise you not to use column names that require quoting.**

```sql
select Policy.[Effective Date], Policy.[Policy #], CLIENT.[NAME], Policy.[Premium], 1 AS ordering
From Policy
JOIN Client ON Client.[CLIENTID] = Policy.[CLIENTID] 
Where Policy.[Effective Date] > '2000-11-11' AND Policy.[Policy Type] <> 'Quote'

union all

select null, null, 'Totals', sum(Policy.[Premium]), 2
From Policy
JOIN Client ON Client.CLIENTID = Policy.CLIENTID
Where Policy.[Effective Date] > '2000-11-11' AND Policy.[Policy Type] <> 'Quote'
Order By Ordering, CLIENT.NAME
```

If you don't want `ordering` to appear in the result then you need to subquery:

```sql
select [Effective Date], [Policy #], [NAME], [Premium]
FROM (
    select Policy.[Effective Date], Policy.[Policy #], CLIENT.[NAME], Policy.[Premium], 1 AS ordering
    From Policy
    JOIN Client ON Client.[CLIENTID] = Policy.[CLIENTID] 
    Where Policy.[Effective Date] > '2000-11-11' AND Policy.[Policy Type] <> 'Quote'

    union all

    select null, null, 'Totals', sum(Policy.[Premium]), 2
    From Policy
    JOIN Client ON Client.CLIENTID = Policy.CLIENTID
    Where Policy.[Effective Date] > '2000-11-11' AND Policy.[Policy Type] <> 'Quote'
)
Order By Ordering, CLIENT.NAME
```

### Grouping Sets

I note that what you are doing here is just a rollup of the first result. So you can actually use the [`GROUPING SETS` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#group-by-grouping-sets--) to get the results you want without extra queries. It will be far more efficient:

```sql
select Policy.[Effective Date], Policy.[Policy #], ISNULL(CLIENT.[NAME], 'Totals') AS Name, SUM(Policy.[Premium])
From Policy
JOIN Client ON Client.[CLIENTID] = Policy.[CLIENTID] 
Where Policy.[Effective Date] > '2000-11-11' AND Policy.[Policy Type] <> 'Quote'
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS (
    (Policy.[Effective Date], Policy.[Policy #], CLIENT.[NAME], Policy.[Premium]),
    ()
)
ORDER BY
    GROUPING_ID(Policy.[Effective Date], Policy.[Policy #], CLIENT.[NAME], Policy.[Premium]),
    CLIENT.[NAME]
```

The [function `GROUPING_ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/grouping-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) returns a 1-bit for every column that is aggregated in that row, so for our total we get bits `1111` which sorts after `0000` for the rest of the results.

Comment: I love the "Grouping Sets". Is there a way to add a column header for the Client Name and Premium? As 'Name' doesn't appear to work

Comment: Have edited that in. There is also `GROUP BY ROLLUP(col1,col2,col3)` but that does a subtotal for each level, which is not what you asked

Comment: That's amazing! 2 Days I've been trying to figure this out. I've seen Grouping sets mentioned but always as part of a much more complicated scenario. Thank you so much!